# Formatting an equation

Tags: math-mode, spacing, formatting, equations

```
\begin{align} \frac{1}{2} (1-\varepsilon^2)\left(\partial_\tau \phi\right)^2
= \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\epsilon ^2\right) \left(
 -\frac{S \epsilon \sin\tau }{\sqrt{\lambda }}
 -\frac{\text{g2} S^2 \epsilon ^2\sin2\tau }{3 \lambda }
 +\epsilon ^3 \left(-\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{54} \text{g2}^2 S  
 \left(32+19 S^2\right) \lambda +Z \left( 
 \frac{35 \text{g2}^4}{27}
 -\frac{7 \text{g2} \text{g4}}{4}+\frac{5 \text{g5}}{8}
 -\frac{\text{g2}^2 \lambda }{6} 
 +\frac{\lambda ^2}{24}\right)\right) \sin\tau }{\lambda ^{5/2}}
 -\frac{S^3 \left(4 \text{g2}^2-3 \lambda \right) \sin3\tau }
       {24 \lambda ^{3/2}}\right)\right)^2 
\end{align}
```

I want to split the equation in my latex file, I have used    `&` `\qquad` but it is not working because of bracket. What else I can do?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, “It’s not working”? Does the equation refuse to render, look strange or have another odd behaviour?

Comment: Without & \qquad . It is working fine but when I want to break the equation then it fails

Comment: If you start a `\left(` on one line, and finish it on another (e.g. `\left( ... \\ ... \right)`), then the compiler borks. Try adding phantom terms such as `right.`, which close the `left` element (e.g. `\left( ... \right. \\ \left. ... \right)`). The `left` and `right` elements on each line have to match. Does that help?

Comment: Got it but little confused , can you apply that into my equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

close an open `\left(` by an `\right.` before you put the linebreak and open it in the next line again with `\left.`

here is the answer:

```
\begin{align*} \frac{1}{2} (1-\varepsilon^2)\left(\partial_\tau \phi\right)^2
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\epsilon ^2\right)\left(
 -\frac{S \epsilon \sin\tau }{\sqrt{\lambda }}
 -\frac{\text{g2} S^2 \epsilon ^2\sin2\tau }{3 \lambda }\right.\\
&\quad\left. +\epsilon ^3 \left(-\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{54} \text{g2}^2 S  
 \left(32+19 S^2\right) \lambda +Z \left( 
 \frac{35 \text{g2}^4}{27}
 -\frac{7 \text{g2} \text{g4}}{4}+\frac{5 \text{g5}}{8}
 -\frac{\text{g2}^2 \lambda }{6} 
 +\frac{\lambda ^2}{24}\right)\right) \sin\tau }
 {\lambda ^{5/2}}\right.\right.\\
 &\quad\left.\left.-\frac{S^3 \left(4 \text{g2}^2-3 \lambda \right) \sin3\tau }
       {24 \lambda ^{3/2}}\right)\right)^2 
\end{align*}
```

Comment: If you do it this way there is no guarantee that the paired delimiters are the same size.

Answer (score 6):

Replace each `\left(` `\right)` by (say) `\Bigl(`  `\Bigr)`  If you choose the size manually in this way then you may split the brackets over lines and alignment cells.

Also, please always post complete documents not just a fragment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*} \frac{1}{2} (1-\varepsilon^2)(\partial_\tau \phi)^2
&= \frac{1}{2} (1-\epsilon ^2) \Biggl(
 -\frac{S \epsilon \sin\tau }{\sqrt{\lambda }}
 -\frac{\text{g2} S^2 \epsilon ^2\sin2\tau }{3 \lambda }\\
&\quad +\epsilon ^3 \Bigl(-\frac{\Bigl(-\frac{1}{54} \text{g2}^2 S  
 (32+19 S^2) \lambda +Z \Bigl( 
 \frac{35 \text{g2}^4}{27}
 -\frac{7 \text{g2} \text{g4}}{4}+\frac{5 \text{g5}}{8}
 -\frac{\text{g2}^2 \lambda }{6} 
 +\frac{\lambda ^2}{24}\Bigr)\Bigr) \sin\tau }{\lambda ^{5/2}}\\
&\qquad -\frac{S^3 (4 \text{g2}^2-3 \lambda) \sin3\tau }
       {24 \lambda ^{3/2}}\Bigr)\Biggr)^2 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: updated with different size brackets

Comment: Why not `multline`?

Comment: @egreg,OP started with `align`:-)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason you want center the three lines. Then you can do the following (observe the commented version with `\left` and `\right`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{c}
\displaystyle
 \frac{1}{2} (1-\varepsilon^2)
\left(
\partial_\tau \phi\right)^2
= \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\epsilon ^2\right) 
%\left(
\Biggl(
 -\frac{S \epsilon \sin\tau }{\sqrt{\lambda }}
 -\frac{\text{g2} S^2 \epsilon ^2\sin2\tau }{3 \lambda }
%\right.
\\
\displaystyle
 +\epsilon ^3
% \left(
\Biggl(
-\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{54} \text{g2}^2 S  
 \left(32+19 S^2\right) \lambda +Z \left( 
 \frac{35 \text{g2}^4}{27}
 -\frac{7 \text{g2} \text{g4}}{4}+\frac{5 \text{g5}}{8}
 -\frac{\text{g2}^2 \lambda }{6} 
 +\frac{\lambda ^2}{24}\right)\right) \sin\tau }{\lambda ^{5/2}}
%\right.
\\
\displaystyle
%\left.\left.
 -\frac{S^3 \left(4 \text{g2}^2-3 \lambda \right) \sin3\tau }
       {24 \lambda ^{3/2}}
%\right)\right)^2 
\Biggr)\Biggr)^2
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]